# Android studio seems to ignore the android:debuggable flag

Tags: android, android-studio

If I set the flag to false and build and run on the phone (using Run, not Debug) it builds the application but seems to be ignoring the debug flag and executing debug only code, logs, etc.  This seems to have only become an issue with the latest Android Studio update 0.1.3.  Is there some configuration I am missing?
Should note that this is not an issue with the same project in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you didn't see this in Eclipse, but this is expected behavior. That's not what the debuggable flag does. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug):

> `android:debuggable`
>      Whether or not the application can be debugged, even when running on a device in user mode — >"`true`" if it can be, and "`false`" if not. The default value is "`false`".

It has nothing to do with "debug only code" or logs.

Comment: Thanks but here is some more detail to clarify: we reference that value to set the applications debug flag:
'DEBUG = (i.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0;'  So, that can be set to false in the manifest, compile/build the application, run it on a phone and the debug flag is either ignored or not being set.

Comment: nevermind.  The problem is something else.  It's a pointless post anyway, should be deleted.